# How to group documents of different types according to the same matching field in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data

To preface, I'm working with Spring Data Elasticsearch.

Let's say I have about 10k documents each of a Car entity and a Owner entity:

```
Car: {VIN, make, model, color}
Owner: {VIN, owner}
```

Let's say that each car can have 0-many owners.
In the end, I want a bunch of CarProfile objects that consist of the matching Car data and Owner data together.

```
CarProfile: {VIN, make, model, color, List<String> owners}
```

I was thinking of two approaches to this:

1. Index all the Car and Owner data into ES. Group the documents by VIN and traverse through each group and convert each group into a CarProfile object.
2. Index all the Owner data into ES. Traverse through the Car data and for each Car, retrieve any matching Owner information with the VIN, then convert all the data to a CarProfile object.

Approach 1 would be more convenient, but I'm not sure if that approach is possible. It seems like aggregations can only give you a subset of the data (like how many owners per car) but not all the document data together. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can check field collapsing. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/collapse-search-results.html)

You can keep documents flat with following document model.

```
CarProfile: {VIN, make, model, color, owner}
```

And you can group by VIN with a query like the below query and this should give you documents grouped by VIN with all of their fields.:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {},
        "collapse": {
            "field": "VIN"
        }
    }
}
```